# Which event needs to called when we put a dynamic value in the textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("#txt1").whichevent(function(){
    $.post("Serversidefile.php?value="+$("#txt1").attr("value"));   

});
```

say we are selecting an item from Select box that value comes in to the Text box 
and i have to Send this text Box value to server side script (PHP ) where i can get the Server side value 
Any events(Load,focus) any idea

Answer (score 1):

why would you want to put the value in a textbox first? `.change()` is what you need :)

Comment: so wait, how does the textbox get filled? what code is used for that? or does the user input text? 

change should work... did you put the code in the $(document).ready ... block?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `change` event:

```
$("#txt1").change(function(){
    $.post("Serversidefile.php?value="+$("#txt1").attr("value"));   
});
```

The `change` event fires when the contents of text box change.

Comment: The Change Event did not work  
//Here txt1 is the text box which Doesnot contain any value and gets the value on selecting an item from select box 
$("#txt1").change(function(){
alert("event Fired");
})

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [select](http://api.jquery.com/select/) event:

```
$("#txt1").select(function() {
    $.post("Serversidefile.php, { value: $(this).val() });   
});
```

Also notice that the value parameter is sent as the data hash and not concatenated in the url in order to be properly encoded.

Comment: The Select Event did not work  
//Here txt1 is the text box which Doesnot contain any value when the document loads  and gets the value on selecting an item from select box 
$("#txt1").select(function(){
alert("event Fired");
})

Comment: @Someone, the select event is triggered whenever you select a text in a textbox with the mouse. Isn't what you were looking for?

Comment: No , 
Here is the problem .i will select a value from  autocomplete Say "ABCDXYZ-JKL".On selecting this value 
So "JKL"  would go in to the  (#TXT1)  So i have to fire the even now  $("txt1").whatEvent(function(){ }) . 
which even need to be fired